# Spring @Autowire with Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, autowired

I am new to Spring and wanted your all assistance. I have run into the "expected single match bean but found two" exception. I have searched for the solution and think have understood the solution. Most solutions suggest using @Qualifier to resolve this exception. However I don't think it will solve my issue. Below is my class hierarchy:

```
abstract class A{

    @Autowired
    Client client;                     

    protected void doSomething(){ 
        /* ....some code .... */
        client.someStuff(); 
        /* ....some code .... */
    }

    /* ..... few abstract methods ......... */
}

class B extends A{ 
    public void action(){ doSomething() }
}

class C extends A{
    public void action(){ doSomething() }
}
```

My .xml confirugration file is

```
    <bean id="authClientA"  class="com.xyz.Client">
        <property name="auth" value="abc">
    </bean>


    <bean id="authClientB"  class="com.xyz.Client">
        <property name="auth" value="xyz">
    </bean>

    <bean id="beanA"  class="ClassA">
        <property name="client"  ref="authClientA">
    </bean>

    <bean id="beanB"  class="ClassB">
        <property name="auth" ref="authClientB">
    </bean>
```

So basically, I have an abstract class which has a method which will be common to both the subclasses. This method uses the client reference but at run time will use different object. `doSomething()` is not overridden in the subclasses.

So when I try to run this code, it gives me the exception for client reference. I dont think I can use @Qualifier because @Qualifier requires to specify bean name from .xml as parameter, but since the 'client' attribute is common, I cant use only one bean name.

Can someone please assist in explaining if there is a way to get around. Duplicating the `doSomething()` method defeats the entire purpose of inheritance and will cause duplicate code across classes. I can't have the `client` attribute in the subclasses as it will become unknown to `doSomething()` method at compile time.

Any ideas/suggestions/solutions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're using XML configuration for these beans, why even use `@Autowired`? Just specify the `property` directly.

Answer (score 0):

`@Qualifier` is the option, you are probably not able to use it.

Modifying your XML:

```
<bean id="authClientA"  class="com.xyz.Client">
    <property name="auth" value="abc">
    <qualifier value="clientA" />
</bean>


<bean id="authClientB"  class="com.xyz.Client">
    <property name="auth" value="xyz">
    <qualifier value="clientB" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanA"  class="ClassA">
    <property name="client"  ref="authClientA">
</bean>

<bean id="beanB"  class="ClassB">
    <property name="auth" ref="authClientB">
</bean>
```

And fixing your class:

```
abstract class A{

      @Qualifier("clientA")
      Client clientA;                     

      @Qualifier("clientB")
      Client clientB;       

      protected void doSomething(){ 
               /* ....some code .... */
               client.someStuff(); /* HERE YOU NEED SOME LOGIC TO INVOKCE THE CORRECT OBJECT METHOD */
               /* ....some code .... */
      }

      /* ..... few abstract methods * ........./
}
```

Also, if you want to understand more, please check this answer here :

[Spring Autowire Annotation on Abstract class: No unique bean is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971288/spring-autowire-annotation-on-abstract-class-no-unique-bean-is-defined)