# Autowiring abstract component

Tags: java, spring

I have a prototype bean factory (`CreateCarAction` is spring bean, scope=prototype):

```
@Component("createCarActionFactory")
public abstract class CreateCarActionFactory  {

    @Lookup
    public abstract CreateCarAction createCarAction();
}
```

and I Autowire it like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("createCarActionFactory")
private CreateCarActionFactory createCarActionFactory;
```

It works when I remove abstract from `CreateCarActionFactory`. When I remove abstract I must implement createCarAction() - I don't need this implementation as @Lookup overrides it. When I resign from `CreateCarActionFactory` I must access `CreateCarAction` form beanFactory, so I jave to Autowire beanFactory, which is also ugly..

Can I autowire abstract `CreateCarActionFactory` `@Component`?

Comment: Why wont you use Provider? ```Provider<CreateCarAction> createCarActionProvider;``` and then you just do ```createCarActionProvider.get()```.

Comment: You cannot autowire abstract class - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15971422/1814524

Comment: hya - I don't understand, where would be the implementation of such Provider? How would it create new class with autowired 2 spring beans? This is the reason why I use Lookup..

Answer (score 0):

You can `autowire` an **interface**, so change CreateCarActionFactory from abstract class into an interface.

Comment: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [mypackage.CreateCarActionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}