# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException throws in the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I had to use common dao class for all common hibernate methods like save, update, find etc. For that I created a BaseDao implementation and this class is extended by all childDao implementation.But when the application runs it throws `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`.
I used `@Qualifier` annotation to clear this problem, it didn't work.May be of my less experience using this annotation,kindly provide the solution for this issue.

```
    @RestController
public class DeviceRestController {
        @Autowired
        EncryptionUtils encryptionUtils;
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
        @Autowired
        MasterDeviceServiceImpl masterDevice;
        ....}

@Service
@Transactional
public class MasterDeviceServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements MasterDeviceService {

    @Autowired
    MasterDeviceDao masterDeviceDao;

    public List<BatchDetails> getAllBatchDetails() {
        return masterDeviceDao.getAllBatchDetails();
    }

    public void addMasterDeviceDetails(MasterDevices masterDevice) {
        masterDeviceDao.addMasterDeviceDetails(masterDevice);

    }












@Service
public interface MasterDeviceService {

    public List<BatchDetails> getAllBatchDetails();

    public void addMasterDeviceDetails(MasterDevices masterDevice);

    public List<MasterDevices> getAllMasterDevicesDetails();

    public List<MasterDevices> getMasterDevicesDetails(String deviceKey);


}






public interface MasterDeviceDao {
    public List<BatchDetails> getAllBatchDetails();

    public void addMasterDeviceDetails(MasterDevices masterDevice);

    public List<MasterDevices> getAllMasterDevicesDetails();

    public List<MasterDevices> getMasterDevicesDetails(String deviceKey);
}








@Repository
public class MasterDeviceDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements MasterDeviceDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<BatchDetails> getAllBatchDetails() {
        List<BatchDetails> batchDetails = template.loadAll(BatchDetails.class);
        return batchDetails;
    }
```

and the second childDao which extend the BaseDao is

```
@RestController
@PropertySource({ "classpath:childCar.properties" })
public class GeneralRestController {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    EncryptionUtils encryptionUtils;
    @Autowired
    DateTimeUtils dateTimeUtils;
    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;
.....}




@Service
public interface UsersService {
    public List<Countries> getAllCountries();

    public List<Countries> getAllCountriesbBydate(Timestamp date);

    public Users getUserDetails(int id);
.........}

public interface UsersDao {
    public List<Countries> getAllCountries();

    public List<Countries> getAllCountriesbBydate(Timestamp date);

    public Users getUserDetails(int id);
.............}




@Service
@Transactional
public class UsersServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements UsersService{
    @Autowired

    UsersDaoImpl usersDao;


    public List<Countries> getAllCountries() {
        return usersDao.getAllCountries();
    }

    public List<Countries> getAllCountriesbBydate(Timestamp date) {
        return usersDao.getAllCountriesbBydate(date);
    }

..............}





@Repository

public class UsersDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements UsersDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<Countries> getAllCountries() {
        return template.loadAll(Countries.class);
    }
.....}
```

and the base class implementation is

```
@Repository
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl implements BaseDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    public <T> void updateObject(T entity) {
        getSession().update(entity);
    }
.........}








    public interface BaseDao {
        public <T> void updateObject(T entity);  

        public <T> List<?> getObject(Class<?> s, int id);

        public void saveObject(Object obj);
    }





@Service
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl implements BaseService {
    @Autowired
    BaseDao baseDao;

    public <T> void updateObject(T entity) {

        baseDao.updateObject(entity);
    }

    public <T> List<?> getObject(Class s, int id) {

        return baseDao.getObject(s, id);

    }

    public void saveObject(Object obj) {
         baseDao.saveObject(obj);
    }

}


@Service
public interface BaseService {
    public <T> void updateObject(T entity);

    public <T> List<?> getObject(Class s, int id);

    public void saveObject(Object obj);
}
```

and the exception is

```
Dec 11, 2018 9:49:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'masterDevice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'masterDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'baseDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.childCar.dao.BaseDao' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: masterDeviceDaoImpl,usersDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'masterDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'baseDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.childCar.dao.BaseDao' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: masterDeviceDaoImpl,usersDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.childCar.dao.BaseDao' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: masterDeviceDaoImpl,usersDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Can't see @qualifier annotation in your code... Can you edit your code

Comment: I think it's a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971288/spring-autowire-annotation-on-abstract-class-no-unique-bean-is-defined?rq=1